# AWS API gateway, 1 lambda with public and private vpc access per and endpoint?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc

I am trying to find out if there is an easy way to have a api gateway with several endpoints that points to a single serverless lambda function (which is a flask web service), to allow only some endpoints internet public access and some that are only internal vpc access?

For example if I have 3 endpoints A,B,C that are all in the same web service running in a lambda function and I want to make A public visible from the internet and B and C only privately visible through a vpn, private vpc. Is this possible? The reason is I want to be able to reduce security checks on the incoming request for internal endpoints.

Comment: can you not just use 2 api gateway endpoints - configure one for public access, the other, protect with a AWS WAF to limit access from your VPC.  Both can trigger the same lambda function.

Comment: I am going to give it a shot here in the next few days. Hopefully this is the best way to accomplish it.

Comment: @Cwissy Yeah that worked well. Any ideas of how to get a vpn to access an api gateway that is private? I have decided that the vpc isn't a great way to access a resource that we need access locally within our vpn.

Comment: @colordoman you may want to investigate https://aws.amazon.com/privatelink/ and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-private-integration.html